# How to Generate a Collection of Instances in Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, collections, instances

I would like a mix of different branches and not just the same instance. I know that it is possible with objects that already exist in a collection in the outliner but is it possible to create a collection dynamically containing a list of instances that have been randomly/dynamically generated with **Geometry Nodes** like the one i boxed in red below?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put all types into **Geometry to Instance** node, And click on **Pick Instance** in **Instance on Points** node

[image]